# For loop for sequentially adjusted regression in R

Tags: r, for-loop, logistic-regression

Most questions related to traditional loops in R are explained away by using functionals with less code and, generally, being more flexible.

However, please correct me, I feel when the order of iterations are important, for loops would still dominate.

In my case, I would like to build a **sequentially and cumulatively adjusted** logistic regression model, store the OR/CIs along with a column showing the what are being adjusted for. This is my expected output:

```
 Model        OR     CI

 Biomarker
 +Age
 +Sex
 +Smoking
```

Here's what I did:

```
df1 <- subset(df, select = c(age_cat, is_female, smoking_category,
                                 bmi_calc, has_diabetes, sbp_mean, 
                                 alcohol_category, highest_education,
                                 occupation, household_income))
model <- data.frame(NULL)

for (i in seq_along(df1)) {

  model <- exp((cbind(OR = coef(glm(as.formula(paste("istroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", i, sep = "+")), 
                         family=binomial, data=df)),
           confint(glm(as.formula(paste("istroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", i, sep = "+")), 
                       family=binomial, data=df)))))


}
```

My outcome variable is stroke (istroke, 0 or 1). My exposure of interest is the biomarker (hscrp_mgl). I know I'm making a fundamental mistake somewhere. I looked for in other SO posts but most of them don't want sequentially and cumulatively adjusted regression models.

Please let me know if this is a duplicate, nonetheless and if anything's unclear.

**EDIT**

My original dataset df contains all the variables of df1, my outcome variable and then some. Here is a reproducible sample of it:

```
age_cat is_female   smoking_category    bmi_calc    has_diabetes        sbp_mean    istroke
(59,69]        0           4            19.6           0                103.5          0
(59,69]        1           1            19.1           0                 138           0
(29,59]        0           4            26.8           0               155.5           0
(29,59]        0           1            23.1           0                 130           1
(29,59]        1           1            22.7           0                 126           1
(59,69]        0           4             25            0               182.5           0
(29,59]        1           1             20            0                  96           1
(29,59]        1           2             23.9          0               134.5           0
(59,69]        0           4             24.4          0               160.5           1
```

**EDIT**
A more reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(50, 60, 50, 40, 70, 90, 30),
             gender = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
             smoke = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4),
             BMI = c(19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25),
             SBP = c(100, 120, 140, 110, 120, 130, 120),
             diab = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
             stroke = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1))
dput(df)
structure(list(age = c(50, 60, 50, 40, 70, 90, 30), gender = c(0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1), smoke = c(4, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4), BMI = c(19, 
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25), SBP = c(100, 120, 140, 110, 120, 130, 
120), diab = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), stroke = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1)), .Names = c("age", "gender", "smoke", "BMI", "SBP", "diab", 
"stroke"), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Would you please provide a reproducible example of df?

Comment: @OmaymaS, please see edit.

Comment: Would you please dput it for example? Just to have sth to start with.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to do that right now... will need some time then to learn and then let you know!

Comment: dput(df1) or dput(head(df1, 10)) and copy the result here. That's how anyone can reproduce the df directly. On the other hand, what you provided is a print of the dataframe, one cannot copy and work on.

Comment: @OmaymaS, done!

Comment: Good. I assume `hscrp_mgl` exists in `df`, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `lapply` might be a better approach in your case over `for` as it can return a collection of data.frames for final row bind instead of expanding *model* iteratively.

Below example randomizes *hscrp_mgl* as it was not in posted data. So ignore results but consider process. Additionally, confidence interval is split between low and high in different columns.

```
set.seed(456)
df <- data.frame(hscrp_mgl = abs(rnorm(250)),
                 age = sample(100, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 gender = sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 smoke = sample(1:4, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 BMI = sample(19:25, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 SBP = sample(c(100, 120, 140, 110, 120, 130, 120),
                              1000, replace=TRUE),
                 diab = sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE),
                 stroke = sample(0:1, 1000, replace=TRUE))  

# ITERATE THROUGH COLUMN NUMBERS (SUBSETTING OUT FIRST AND LAST)
modeldfs <- lapply(seq_along(df)[3:ncol(df)-1], function(i) {
  strf <- paste("stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", 
                paste(names(df)[2:i], collapse = "+"), sep = "+")
  print(strf)

  # FIT DYNAMIC CUMULATIVE FORMULA USING names() TO PASS IN COLUMN NAME
  fit <- glm(as.formula(strf), family=binomial, data=df)

  # BIND MODEL STATS
  data.frame(OR = exp(coef(fit)[i+1]), 
             CI_2.5 = exp(confint(fit)[i+1,1]), 
             CI_97.5 = exp(confint(fit)[i+1,2]))
})

model <- do.call(rbind, modeldfs)
model
```

Output

```
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age+gender"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age+gender+smoke"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age+gender+smoke+BMI"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age+gender+smoke+BMI+SBP"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
[1] "stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)+age+gender+smoke+BMI+SBP+diab"
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
# > model <- do.call(rbind, modeldfs)
# > model
             OR    CI_2.5  CI_97.5
age    1.003285 0.9989043 1.007701
gender 1.067117 0.8318796 1.369055
smoke  1.005926 0.9005196 1.123717
BMI    1.011281 0.9505659 1.075928
SBP    1.003252 0.9929368 1.013692
diab   1.139586 0.8880643 1.462925
```

Comment: Thanks for the take @Parfait. However, perhaps it was not clear from the post, I want **cumulatively adjusted** ORs and CIs. So in the first iteration, it may be stroke ~ hscrp (crude model), but the next iterations should give me ORs for stroke ~ hscrp + age, then ORs for stroke ~ hscrp + age + gender... etc. Hence, my need for a traditional loop than functionals as the order of the sequential and cumulative iterations is important here.

Comment: You can actually still use `lapply` using `paste(..., collapse)` on a dynamic range of column names in formula. See edit with formula printed out.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Parfait! This seems right on the money. I'll check this when I'm back at my dept on Monday and let you know how it goes!                          PS: its really elegant!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the dataframe with `hscrp_mgl` to reproduce the result and make sure it is the same as what you want, but you could try the following approach:

Get the names of all the features you'd like to use in the iterations:

```
x <-  setdiff(names(df), "stroke")
```

**Using `purrr::map`**

Create a dataframe with the first column with the features names and use `purrr::map` to mutate the values you want.

```
library(purrr)

model <- data_frame(Model = x) %>% 
  mutate(OR = map(Model, ~coef(glm(as.formula(paste("stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", .x, sep = "+")), 
                                   family=binomial, data=df))),
         CI = map(Model, ~confint(glm(as.formula(paste("stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", .x, sep = "+")), 
                                   family=binomial, data=df)))
```

You will get sth like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
   Model        OR            CI
   <chr>    <list>        <list>
1    age <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
2 gender <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
3  smoke <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
4    BMI <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
5    SBP <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
6   diab <dbl [3]> <dbl [3 × 2]>
```

**Using `Purrr::map` and `broom`**

You can also use `broom` functions to extract the data you want from the model as follows:

- Add the model results in one column
- Get the coef using `tidy` and mutate and add `OR` column
- Get conf. intervals using `confint_tidy` and add `CI` column

---

```
model2 <- data_frame(Model = x) %>% 
  mutate(model_details = map(Model, ~glm(as.formula(paste("stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", .x, sep = "+")), 
                                   family=binomial, data=df))) %>% 
  mutate(OR = map(model_details, broom::tidy),
         CI = map(model_details, broom::confint_tidy))
```

**Cumulative adjustment**

For cumulative adjustment, you can try the following:

```
model <- data_frame(Model = cnames) %>% 
  mutate(Model_adjust = map2_chr(Model, seq_along(Model), ~paste(cnames[1:.y], collapse = "+"))) %>% 
  mutate(model_details = map(Model_adjust, ~glm(as.formula(paste("stroke ~ log2(hscrp_mgl)", .x, sep = "+")), 
                                         family=binomial, data=df))) %>% 
  mutate(OR = map(model_details, broom::tidy),
         CI = map(model_details, broom::confint_tidy))
```

The additional step adds a column with the included variables, then the following steps use Model_adjust to fit the models:

```
model <- data_frame(Model = cnames) %>% 
    mutate(Model_adjust = map2_chr(Model, seq_along(Model), ~paste(cnames[1:.y], collapse = "+")))

    # A tibble: 6 × 2
       Model                  Model_adjust
       <chr>                         <chr>
    1    age                           age
    2 gender                    age+gender
    3  smoke              age+gender+smoke
    4    BMI          age+gender+smoke+BMI
    5    SBP      age+gender+smoke+BMI+SBP
    6   diab age+gender+smoke+BMI+SBP+diab
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @OmaymaS. Is this giving me ORs for individual relationships like stroke ~ hscrp + age, then stroke ~ hscrp + gender? Or is it cumulatively adjusting for the variables, like stroke ~ hscrp + age, then next stroke ~ hscrp + age + gender... etc. I want the latter... ORs and CIs in a tabular format for sequential and cumulative adjustemtns of the model.

Comment: @Mak 
Check the added cumulative adjustment section

Comment: Thanks @OmaymaS. Although I found the broom package immensely helpful, I think Parfait's approach is more appropriate for my purposes.